# Dataset: create a column that is a running total of another column

Tags: dataset

I have a column of integers `"Points"` and I want to add another column that is a running total of that column.  Here is my data:

```
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-09", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -4, "Points" -> 0|>, 
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-13", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-15", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -3, "Points" -> 0|>, 
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-17", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 1, "Points" -> 2|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-19", "OT" -> "SO", "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-20", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -3, "Points" -> 0|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-22", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 2,  "Points" -> 2|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-24", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-27", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 1, "Points" -> 2|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-29", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-10-31", "OT" -> "SO", "GoalDiff" -> 1, "Points" -> 2|>,
<|"Date" -> "2011-11-03", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 3, "Points" -> 2|>,
```

So my running total column would be

```
0
0
0
2
2
2
4
4
6
6
8
10
```

Think of a check book where one column is the credit/debit and the next column is the balance (I know, we don't balance check books any more but a spreadsheet will do the same thing).

The `Total` won't work because it sums the whole column whereas I want the sum only up to the current row.

It's simple to do this in Excel, but is there some magic to do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"Date" -> "2011-10-09", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -4, 
    "Points" -> 0|>, <|"Date" -> "2011-10-13", "OT" -> "", 
    "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>, <|"Date" -> "2011-10-15", 
    "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -3, "Points" -> 0|>, <|
    "Date" -> "2011-10-17", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 1, 
    "Points" -> 2|>, <|"Date" -> "2011-10-19", "OT" -> "SO", 
    "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>, <|"Date" -> "2011-10-20", 
    "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -3, "Points" -> 0|>, <|
    "Date" -> "2011-10-22", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 2, 
    "Points" -> 2|>, <|"Date" -> "2011-10-24", "OT" -> "", 
    "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>, <|"Date" -> "2011-10-27", 
    "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 1, "Points" -> 2|>, <|
    "Date" -> "2011-10-29", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -1, 
    "Points" -> 0|>, <|"Date" -> "2011-10-31", "OT" -> "SO", 
    "GoalDiff" -> 1, "Points" -> 2|>, <|"Date" -> "2011-11-03", 
    "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 3, "Points" -> 2|>}]

Module[{acc = 0}, ds[All, <|#, "CumulativePoints" -> (acc += #Points)|> &]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like your solution, +1.  Please forgive me, but I have taken the liberty to write a response which generalizes from this starting point (it was too large to fit into a comment).

Comment: @WReach I have learned so much about the internals of `Dataset` from your very detailed answers. Thank you so much for that.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.

Answer (score 3):

I, too, would likely use the [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/257371/142) given by [Rohit Namjoshi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/58370/rohit-namjoshi).

This can also be written in a slightly modified yet equivalent form:

```
dataset[All, Module[{t = 0}, <|#, "Running" -> (t += #Points)|> &]]
```

This alternate form allows us to define a generalized operator...

```
running[init_, accumulate_, update_] :=
  Module[{r = init}, (r = accumulate[#, r]; update[#, r])&]
```

and then use it:

```
dataset[All, running[0, #Points + #2 &, <|#, "Running" -> #2|> &]]
```

Given...

```
dataset = {
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-09", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -4, "Points" -> 0|>, 
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-13", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-15", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -3, "Points" -> 0|>, 
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-17", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 1, "Points" -> 2|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-19", "OT" -> "SO", "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-20", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -3, "Points" -> 0|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-22", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 2,  "Points" -> 2|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-24", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-27", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 1, "Points" -> 2|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-29", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> -1, "Points" -> 0|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-10-31", "OT" -> "SO", "GoalDiff" -> 1, "Points" -> 2|>,
  <|"Date" -> "2011-11-03", "OT" -> "", "GoalDiff" -> 3, "Points" -> 2|>
} // Dataset
```

... both of these variations return:

[image: dataset snapshot]

Some other possibilities...

```
dataset[Transpose /* (<|#, "Running" -> Accumulate[#Points]|> &) /* Transpose]
```

```
dataset[{All, Query[Accumulate, "Points"]} /* MapThread[<|#, "Running" -> #2|> &]]
```

```
dataset[{All, Query[Accumulate, <|"Running" -> #Points|> &]} /* MapThread[Join]]
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where it would be nice if `SubsetMap` worked on associations.

Comment: +1 Very nice generalization and alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

```
SubsetMap[Accumulate, {All, -1}]  @ ds[All, <|#, "CumulativePoints" -> #Points|> &]
```

[image]

Some variations that give the same result:

```
SubsetMap[Accumulate, {All, -1}]  @* Map[<|#, "CumulativePoints" -> #Points|> &] @ ds

ds // Map[<|#, "CumulativePoints" -> #Points|> &] // SubsetMap[Accumulate, {All, -1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Accumulate`:

```
output = Accumulate[input]
```

Comment: In a Dataset it would be like this:  `ds2 = ds[All, <|#, "TotalPoints" -> Accumulate["Points"]|> &]`.  But that fails with `Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Accumulate[Points]`.